# Unity: Use automatic navigation in explicit navigation

Tags: unity-game-engine, navigation

I want to use explicit navigation for all buttons in application.
But for some buttons I want leave the "Select on Right" to use the automatic navigation (for example: I know the next buttons for left, up and down but I don't know the next right button).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a custom `Selectable` that can use explicit navigation if values are setted. You can use this code for your case, just leave empty fields from inspector where you need to use automatic navigation.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace UI.CustomSelectable
{
    public class CustomSelectable : Selectable
    {
        [SerializeField]
        private Selectable upSelectable;

        [SerializeField]
        private Selectable downSelectable;

        [SerializeField]
        private Selectable leftSelectable;

        [SerializeField]
        private Selectable rightSelectable;

        public override Selectable FindSelectableOnUp()
        {
            return upSelectable != null ? upSelectable : base.FindSelectableOnUp();
        }

        public override Selectable FindSelectableOnDown()
        {
            return downSelectable != null ? downSelectable : base.FindSelectableOnDown();
        }

        public override Selectable FindSelectableOnLeft()
        {
            return leftSelectable != null ? leftSelectable : base.FindSelectableOnLeft();
        }

        public override Selectable FindSelectableOnRight()
        {
            return rightSelectable != null ? rightSelectable : base.FindSelectableOnRight();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me with how to use it?

Comment: Create a class named "CustomSelectable.cs", paste the code, remove button script from your ui button and add this component.

Comment: Hi, this is great solution for me but ı have a question with this code it only add navigation options. "Onclick" removed. How can ı add it? Do you have any sugestion?

Comment: Depends on what you want. `OnClick` is a serialized method of class `Button`, it's not inherited by it. If you want the functionality that @Liolik implemented above with ability to be clicked on, you could implement interface [IPointerClickHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html). IMHO better option would be to create a new class that inherits from Button and just override FindSelectableOn methods just as Liolik did in his answer. This way you get basically Button Component but with custom behavior. If you want I could provide and example.

Answer (score 4):

I wrote a Custom Button class based on the overriding Find...() method idea. Maybe it will be useful to others.
It adds some convenience features to the original answer like lists of possible selection candidates and inspector buttons to automatically populate your selection candidates.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds lists for each navigation direction.
    /// The first valid selectable in each list will be used or (if none is valid)
    /// then auto navigation will be used as fallback.
    /// </summary>
    public class ButtonSmartNavigation : Button
    {
        public List<Selectable> UpSelectables;
        public List<Selectable> DownSelectables;
        public List<Selectable> LeftSelectables;
        public List<Selectable> RightSelectables;

        public override Selectable FindSelectableOnUp()
        {
            var upSelectable = getFirstSelectable(UpSelectables, this.navigation.selectOnUp);
            return upSelectable != null ? upSelectable : base.FindSelectableOnUp();
        }

        public override Selectable FindSelectableOnDown()
        {
            var downSelectable = getFirstSelectable(DownSelectables, this.navigation.selectOnDown);
            return downSelectable != null ? downSelectable : base.FindSelectableOnDown();
        }

        public override Selectable FindSelectableOnLeft()
        {
            var leftSelectable = getFirstSelectable(LeftSelectables, this.navigation.selectOnLeft);
            return leftSelectable != null ? leftSelectable : base.FindSelectableOnLeft();
        }

        public override Selectable FindSelectableOnRight()
        {
            var rightSelectable = getFirstSelectable(RightSelectables, this.navigation.selectOnRight);
            return rightSelectable != null ? rightSelectable : base.FindSelectableOnRight();
        }

        protected Selectable getFirstSelectable(List<Selectable> list, Selectable defaultExplicit)
        {
            if (list == null)
                return null;

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                if (list[i] != null && list[i].IsInteractable() && list[i].gameObject.activeInHierarchy)
                {
                    return list[i];
                }
            }

            return defaultExplicit;
        }

        public void AddUpSelectable(Selectable selectable, bool prioritize = false)
        {
            addSelectable(UpSelectables, selectable, prioritize);
        }

        public void AddDownSelectable(Selectable selectable, bool prioritize = false)
        {
            addSelectable(DownSelectables, selectable, prioritize);
        }

        public void AddLeftSelectable(Selectable selectable, bool prioritize = false)
        {
            addSelectable(LeftSelectables, selectable, prioritize);
        }

        public void AddRightSelectable(Selectable selectable, bool prioritize = false)
        {
            addSelectable(RightSelectables, selectable, prioritize);
        }

        protected void addSelectable(List<Selectable> list, Selectable selectable, bool prioritize)
        {
            if (list == null)
            {
                list = new List<Selectable>();
            }

            if (prioritize)
            {
                list.Insert(0, selectable);
            }
            else
            {
                list.Add(selectable);
            }
        }

        public void Clear()
        {
            UpSelectables.Clear();
            DownSelectables.Clear();
            LeftSelectables.Clear();
            RightSelectables.Clear();
        }
    }

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    [CustomEditor(typeof(ButtonSmartNavigation), true)]
    [CanEditMultipleObjects]
    public class ButtonSmartNavigationEditor : UnityEditor.UI.ButtonEditor
    {
        protected SerializedProperty upSelectables;
        protected SerializedProperty downSelectables;
        protected SerializedProperty leftSelectables;
        protected SerializedProperty rightSelectables;

        public override void OnInspectorGUI()
        {
            base.OnInspectorGUI();

            var target = this.target as ButtonSmartNavigation;

            if (upSelectables == null) upSelectables = serializedObject.FindProperty("UpSelectables");
            if (downSelectables == null) downSelectables = serializedObject.FindProperty("DownSelectables");
            if (leftSelectables == null) leftSelectables = serializedObject.FindProperty("LeftSelectables");
            if (rightSelectables == null) rightSelectables = serializedObject.FindProperty("RightSelectables");

            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Smart Navigation", EditorStyles.boldLabel);

            GUILayout.BeginHorizontal();
            if (GUILayout.Button("Up"))
            {
                target.UpSelectables.Clear();
                target.AddUpSelectable(target.FindSelectableOnUp());
                EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
            }
            if (GUILayout.Button("Down"))
            {
                target.DownSelectables.Clear();
                target.AddDownSelectable(target.FindSelectableOnDown());
                EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
            }
            if (GUILayout.Button("Left"))
            {
                target.LeftSelectables.Clear();
                target.AddLeftSelectable(target.FindSelectableOnLeft());
                EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
            }
            if (GUILayout.Button("Right"))
            {
                target.RightSelectables.Clear();
                target.AddRightSelectable(target.FindSelectableOnRight());
                EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
            }
            if (GUILayout.Button("Clear"))
            {
                target.Clear();
                EditorUtility.SetDirty(target);
            }
            GUILayout.EndHorizontal();

            serializedObject.Update();
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(upSelectables, new GUIContent("Up Selectables"));
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(downSelectables, new GUIContent("Down Selectables"));
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(leftSelectables, new GUIContent("Left Selectables"));
            EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(rightSelectables, new GUIContent("Right Selectables"));
            serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
        }
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: This worked great but I had to copy it and adjust for a Toggle ... but now I have a button with a toggle in it the I Instantiate from a prefab ... navigates fine between the 2 and is set to automatic for the rest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other answers, I wrote my own version of button with hybrid navigation. To avoid redefining fields, I reused the `selectOnXXX` fields of Selectable, but in counterpart, I avoid calling `base.FindSelectableOnXXX` methods because those use the navigation mode, and in order to set the `selectOnXXX` fields (at least in Inspector Normal mode), you want to use Explicit mode or the fields won't appear.

So instead, I directly use `FindSelectable` (called by `base.FindSelectableOnXXX` methods when Automatic). `navigation.mode` is therefore ignored (when it comes to directions at least).

```cs
/// HybridNavigationButton mixes Explicit and Automatic navigation
/// It ignores navigation.mode for directions (if None, it will still disable selection
/// in Selectable.OnPointerDown).
/// It's not possible to force set no Selectable in a given direction, as null is
/// considered a no-override, but this should cover most cases of bad Automatic navigation.
public class HybridNavigationButton : Button
{
    // In each directional method, use selectable set for navigation as an override
    // If not set, fallback to Automatic navigation, calling FindSelectable directly
    // to avoid depending on navigation.mode

    public override Selectable FindSelectableOnLeft()
    {
        return navigation.selectOnLeft != null ? navigation.selectOnLeft
            : FindSelectable(Vector3.left);
    }

    public override Selectable FindSelectableOnRight()
    {
        return navigation.selectOnRight != null ? navigation.selectOnRight
            : FindSelectable(Vector3.right);
    }

    public override Selectable FindSelectableOnUp()
    {
        return navigation.selectOnUp != null ? navigation.selectOnUp
            : FindSelectable(Vector3.up);
    }

    public override Selectable FindSelectableOnDown()
    {
        return navigation.selectOnDown != null ? navigation.selectOnDown
            : FindSelectable(Vector3.down);
    }
}
```